# IndexError: list index out of range in Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, anaconda

I have written some code below In Python 3.7(64 bit) & Anaconda 1.9.7.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import glob
import os

data = data.join(data.pop('Serial Number')
               .str.strip(',')
               .str.split(',', expand=True)
               .stack()
               .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
               .rename('Serial Number')).reset_index(drop=True)
data['Serial Number']
```

**After running this file i got below error message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "servicereport.py", line 70, in <module>
.str.split(',', expand=True)     
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am not getting what exactly missing in this as this code is running on system on which it is created.
How can I fix this error?

Comment: Please share a sample of your data

Comment: I can't share data as it is confidencial but my data is .xlsm file which having multiple columns in which serial number column having duplicate numbers and unique numbers

Comment: For example below is my xlsm file data                                                                 
  ID             | Country
| 1              | USA, Germany, Mexico 
| 2              | Brazil, Canada
| 3              | Peru                                                                                                       I want show output like this:ID             | Country
| 1              | USA
| 1              | Germany
| 1              | Mexico
| 2              | Brazil
| 2              | Canada

Comment: `.str.split(',', expand=True)` do you want to split by `,`, I think it should split by `|` right?